# Upload not working in vaadin 6.4.8

Tags: vaadin

I am using upload component to upload a file. I have added `receiverUpload()` method to get the outputstream of the file. But its not at all calling the method. When I click on upload, browser starts loading, but nothing is happening behind.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should update to 6.5.4. As far as I remember there were some fixes regarding upload.